# change size of a rectangle during runtime in objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hi guys i have a quick question
I am using xcode to build an app and I want to **animate the size of a custom rectangle during runtime.**

I have a UIView class where i create custom rectangles and draw them on the screen of the ViewController. The problem is, whenever i start the app, it just create all the rectangles and then shows the screen.
What i want it to do is to show the screen and then animate the rectangles (like a "growing-animation")

This is how i create the rectangles in the UIView class

```
-(void)newRectWithX:(int) x  height:(int) height{

    _rdmRed = arc4random_uniform(100);
    _rdmRed /= 100;
    _rdmGreen = arc4random_uniform(100);
    _rdmGreen /= 100;
    _rdmBlue= arc4random_uniform(100);
    _rdmBlue /= 100;

    _color = [UIColor colorWithRed:_rdmRed green:_rdmGreen blue:_rdmBlue alpha:0.6];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:50 delay:10 options:UIViewAnimationOptionShowHideTransitionViews
                     animations:^{

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGRect rectangle = CGRectMake(x,0,4,height);
    CGContextAddRect(context, rectangle);
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [_color CGColor]);
    CGContextFillRect(context, rectangle);

                     }
                     completion:nil];

}
```

I didn't do anything in the ViewController class yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

+ animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:

Animate changes to one or more views using the specified duration, delay, options, and completion handler.

To be able to use that method you will need to animate a view. Here is a chuck of code that will allow you to use that method and CoreGraphics.

```
@implementation View
{
    UIView * view;
}

- (void)runAnimation {

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(setNeedsDisplay) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

    view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 10)];


    [UIView animateWithDuration:1 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionShowHideTransitionViews animations:^{

        view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20);

    } completion:nil];

}


// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    // Drawing code

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGRect rectangle = ((UIView *)[view.layer presentationLayer]).frame;
    CGContextAddRect(context, rectangle);
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor cyanColor].CGColor);
    CGContextFillRect(context, rectangle);

}

@end
```

Comment: thanks! what kind of syntax is behind the { UIView * view } ? also how do i draw the rectangles on my screen? where should i call the -()runAnimation method?

Comment: Call runAnimation when you want the rectangle to scale... if you want to post some more of your code, I would be glad to help direct you.

Answer (score 0):

I have this to move a rectangle, maybe can help you

if(destination.origin.x > 0){
                destination.origin.x = 0;
                [self.navigationController.view.superview bringSubviewToFront:self.navigationController.view];
            }else{
                destination.origin.x += _sideMenu.view.frame.size.width;
            }

```
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
            self.view.frame = destination;
        }completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            if(finished){
                if (destination.origin.x > 0) {
                    [self.navigationController.view.superview bringSubviewToFront:_sideMenu.view];
                } else {
                }
            }
        }];
```

change the destination.origin to  destination.size, like this

```
CGRect destination = self.view.frame;

        if(destination.size.height > 10){
            destination.size.height = 10;
            [self.navigationController.view.superview bringSubviewToFront:self.navigationController.view];
        }else{
            destination.size.height += 10;
        }

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
            self.view.frame = destination;
        }completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            if(finished){
                if (destination.size.height > 10) {
                    [self.navigationController.view.superview bringSubviewToFront:_sideMenu.view];
                } else {
                }
            }
        }];
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't fully understand it yet but it doesn't seem to complicated

Comment: What does the [self.navigationController.view.superview bringSubviewToFront:self.navigationController.view]; do?

Comment: that line put the new view in front of the main view... I think you need to focus on animateWithDuration, maybe i´m wrong but i think the you don't need bringSubviewToFront function